# embed a PDF page in plain XeTeX

Tags: xetex, pdf, dvipdfmx

In the dvipdfm documetation, there is a special command for including the first page of an embedded pdf (using `\special{pdf:epdf ... (file.pdf)}`. Is there a way to insert for instance the fifth page of a pdf file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [XeTeX reference](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/xetexref), it should be as simple as `\XeTeXpdffile <filename> [page <int>]`, so, for example:

```
\hoffset-1in\voffset-1in\advance\hsize by1in\advance\vsize by1in
\nopagenumbers
\XeTeXpdffile "XeTeX-reference.pdf" page 16
\bye
```

should give you the 16th page of the reference file, which includes information on other options you can use.

Comment: I knew I saw it somewhere. Thanks, that will do it.

Comment: This has a scale option with, just have to append the scale/xscale/width/… word, and then the scaling.